# pyqt - How do I ensure that all my calculations are running in a separate Qthread?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qthread

I have been reading around about how to "properly" use QThreads and I've become a bit confused. I've been reading around and a lot of people have been saying to, create a QThread, but also create a worker which is a QObject. Then use movetoThread to move the Qobject to the Qthread.

I'm just a bit confused since all the examples I've seen on stackoverflow don't really do that.

If this is my code:

```
class worker(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        Qthread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        do_work()
        a = 3

    def do_work(self):
        b = 2

        self.emit(SIGNAL("work_done"),b)

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.worker_thread = worker()

        self.connect(self.worker,SIGNAL('work_done'),self.done)

        self.worker_thread.start()

    def done(self,b)

        print "the value from the worker is: " + str(b)
```

Will this code make the assignment of variables `a` and `b` done in another thread SEPARATE from the main thread? Or is that not true as my `worker_thread` object LIVES INSIDE the main thread?

Answer (score -1):

A better method for running some code in another thread is not to subclass `QThread`, but to move the object implementing that other code into a separate thread.

In your case, your `worker` object would just inherit directly from `QObject`, so that you can communicate with it across threads via signals and slots. Then create a standard, out-of-the-box `QThread` and move the `worker` to it. Use signals/slots to send the worker data, if needed, and to retrieve its results when they're ready.

I think your confusion stems from this idea: the `QThread` object *manages* a separate thread, but the *object itself* lives in whatever thread created the object in the first place. For example, creating it in the main thread means the `QThread` is also in the main thread, but your `worker` object would be in the thread managed by the `QThread` object (after you move it there, of course).

Check out [this post](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) for more details and explanations.

Comment: The post you linked to is obsolete, and has been superceded by [QThread: You were not doing so wrong](https://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html). Executive summary: If you don't need an event-loop in the worker thread (which is very often the case), just subclass `QThread` and reimplement `run`.

Comment: @ekhumoro It's not obsolete, it really depends on what you're doing in the separate thread. If you just want to run some encapsulated code, then subclassing and reimplementing `run()` is fine. But if you want an object with which you can communicate, it's better to use the approach I give here.

Comment: No, It is really is obsolete. It says the official Qt thread docs are wrong (which they no longer are), and it also claims "to sub-class [QThread] and implement your own run() function, is very wrong" - which is also clearly incorrect. Please read the other blog post I linked to understand the history on this subject - it's not very long, and it properly reflects the advice given in the current Qt docs.